Trigger event when searched term is found jQuery
When a user presses Ctrl + F (PC) or Cmd + F (Mac) in a browser, a search field pops up allowing you to search for a word. If it finds a word, it highlights it on the page. So in the example below, if you search for "pink" it will pull two results, and you can navigate to each one.
So here's my question: when it finds a word and highlights it, can you detect that event and trigger an action? For example, highlight the found word in red and make it bold?
      <h2>Section with a Paragraph</h2>
      <p>Here is some text content</p>
      <h2>Section with a Div and Mixed Content</h2>
      <div>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Here is some content with text and a link.</p>
        <p><a href="https://duckduckgo.com" target="_blank">Duck Duck Go</a></p>
        <p>Pink</p>
      </div>
      <h2>Section with a List</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Dogs</li>
        <li>Cats</li>
      </ul>
      <h2>Section with an article</h2>
      <article>
        <p>This is an <code>&lt;article&gt;</code> element</p>
        <p>Pink</p>
      </article>


This is just HTML. Please share your code attempts you have tried so far

I don't think there are any find-related events. Scroll events will be triggered, but that's it.

@Death-is-the-real-truth I haven't tried anything so far because I don't know what to try

window.getSelection() won't return the highlighted browser text - the result of using the Find tool. What you could do is create a custom Search input. https://github.com/rokobuljan/hilite

@RokoC.Buljan won't work for my purposes. This is for accessibility purposes for screen reader users when they are trying to search for content on a page using the browser.
